# PHP object creation at run time

Tags: php, object

I am trying to build a project in which links to different pages(php) are given on a page. I have a variable which gets the unique id from the link and accordingly displays content based on the id. The user is allowed to delete/edit the content.
 When a user clicks two(or more) links  one after the other, the second's link id is stored in the variable and  if the user presses the delete button on the first link's page the second one gets deleted as the variable has the id from the second(last pressed) link.
 I don't want the variable to get modified and each link should be treated as a separate entity. Please tell me how to solve this problem.
A unique id is sent to the class through the link and based on the id content is displayed to the user.There is an option to edit/delete the content and if two links are clicked the id is getting overwritten and the wrong content is deleted. In order to avoid that i want an object created every time so that each object will have its own variables and id is not overwritten

Comment: Sidenote: you should use `__construct()` not php4 style constructor (actually, you're mixing the two it seems, or is it `__L()` a regular method?); anyway, you could go with AJAX, but exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why are you trying to create an entire class when a link is clicked? I'm sure there is another way to achieve what you want (if you exactly tell us).

Comment: A new instance (object) of the `L` class or an instance of a completely different class?

Comment: A new instance has to be created every time a link is clicked

Comment: A unique id is sent to the class through the link and based on the id content is displayed to the user.There is an option to edit/delete the content and if two links are clicked the id is getting overwritten and the wrong content is deleted. In order to avoid that i want an object created every time so that each object will have its own variables and id is not overwritten

Comment: Please read this and update your question afterwards: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

You could pass something in from the query string or some other request context variable.